# EntityCollection OrderBy problem

Tags: c#, linq

What is wrong with the following code?

List students = new List();

```
students = db.Students.Where(c => c.StudentCourses.OrderBy(o => o.EnrolledTo > DateTime.Now.Date)).ToList();
```

I am getting error: delegate does not take 1 arguments.

Thanks

Comment: This is nonsensical. Can you explain in English what you are trying to do?

Comment: I would expect that the value returned by your lambda be something that is comparable (sortable). In this case all the values will either be true or false (unless EnrolledTo has multiple values, in which case I would expect an exception if you don't use First(), Max, etc.). You comparison seems to be more appropriate for selection (Where, First, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guessing a bit here, but I think that you are trying to get the latest date from each student and compare it to todays date. If you do it using `OrderBy` you would need a `Last` call to get the single value, but you should rather just use `Max`.

Note: Don't use `DateTime.Now` in a loop, as the value changes. If you run the query at midnight it may change in the middle of the loop, and you get an inconsistent result. Put the value in a variable before the loop.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
students = db.Students
  .Where(c => c.StudentCourses.Max(o => o.EnrolledTo) > today)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: +1. But since he's returning a list, I'm assuming he just wants to sort the students by enrol date. He should use select rather than where (and then get rid of Max/Last)

Comment: I want a list of students whose courses have not finished yet, i.e enrolledto date > today.

Comment: thanks for that. Should I use the Where instead of the Select then?

Comment: @user583341: If you are referring to Robs suggestion, that is based on the assumption that you didn't want to filter the result at all. As you do want to filter the result, you need the `Where`.